# The states in this FSM machine are changing too quickly due to an issue with the clock updating the present state

Tags: verilog, state-machine

I'm in the process of implementing a finite state machine in verilog, and I've encountered an issue. However, I know what the problem is, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my current code:

```
module moore_SM(clk, rstn, btn, z, rstLED, state);

  //Port Assignments
  input clk, rstn;
  input [2:0] btn;
  output  z;
  output reg rstLED;
  output reg [5:0] state;

  //Internal Port Assignments
  reg [1:0] w, x; //NOTE: This is typically the input in FSM, 
                  //but it is internal because there is a conversion from btn to w.
  reg [2:0] y, Y; //Present state and next state respectively
  reg [2:0] pstBtn; 
  reg [31:0] cnt;

  //Define some parameters
      //Input Type (i.e. A, B or C)
      parameter [1:0] A = 2'b00, B = 2'b01, C = 2'b11, DC = 2'b10; //DC => don't care - shouldn't affect FSM

      //State (i.e. S1, S2, S3, S4, S5 or S6)
      parameter [2:0] S1 = 3'b000, S2 = 3'b001, S3 = 3'b010, S4 = 3'b011, S5 = 3'b100, S6 = 3'b101;

  initial begin 
      state = 0;
  end

  //Determine which button is active
  always @(*)
      begin
            case(btn)
                3'b110: begin w = A; end
                3'b101: begin w = B; end
                3'b011: begin w = C; end
            //  default: w = DC;
            endcase
      end

  //Define the next state and output combinational circuits
  always @(w,y)
    begin
        case(y)

            S1: begin
                    state = 6'b000001;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end

            S2: begin
                    state = 6'b000010;
                    if(w == B) begin Y = S3; end
                    else begin if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else Y = S1; end
                 end

            S3: begin
                    state = 6'b000100;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin if(w == B) begin Y = S4; end
                    else Y = S1; end 
                 end

            S4: begin
                    state = 6'b001000;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S5; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end

            S5: begin
                    state = 6'b010000;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin if(w == B) begin Y = S3; end
                    else Y = S6; end
                 end

            S6: begin 
                    state = 6'b100000;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end

            //default: Y = 3'b111;

        endcase

      end

    //assign z = (Y == S2);

  //Define the sequential block
  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        y <= Y;
    end

endmodule
```

This code is supposed to identify the pattern ABBAC. I believe the logic accomplishes this purpose.

However, I've encountered a problem. When I press one of the three buttons, the first always block - `always @(*)` - executes and evaluates the change. The state of the button is encoded and saved into `w.` At the same time, the next always block - `always @(w,y)` - senses a change and determines in which state to reside. Like I expected, if I send input `A`, the machine moves from `S1` into `S2`.

Now if I send input `B`, the machine moves back into state `S1`. After I changed a few things around, I identified what I believe to be the problem. Note the last always block: `always @(posedge clk).` This always block continuously updates the present state, `y.` When I press a button, I assume what is happening is that the second always block, `always @(w,y),` is receiving an updated `y` at 50mHz (in my case), which is obviously much faster than I can press and release a button. Assuming I'm pressing the `B` button while in state `S2`, the state quickly changes to `S3` to `S4` and then to `S1` because of the continuous update.

That said, I'm having some trouble coming up with a way to fix this issue. I basically need some way to change only one state per button press.

Note that I'm primarily testing this code on an experimental board. I did write a testbench, but the simulation does not seem to match what I'm seeing on the design board. In case anyone wants to see the testbench code, I posted it below:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module moore_SM_TB();
    reg clk;
    reg [2:0] btn;
    wire [5:0] state;
    wire z;
    wire rstLED;

  initial begin 
    clk = 1;
    #0 btn = 3'b111;
    #50 btn = 3'b110;
    #50 btn = 3'b111;
    #50 btn = 3'b101;
    #50 btn = 3'b111;
    #50 btn = 3'b011;
    #50 btn = 3'b111;
 end

always begin
  #20 clk = ~clk;    
end

  //MUT
  moore_SM MUT (clk, 0, btn, z, rstLED, state);

endmodule
```

NOTE: I believe the solution will ultimately involve modifying how the buttons are handled. When I release a button, this also registers as a change. Hence, I had to comment out the default case because it would also mess up which state the machine is in.

UPDATE: I wrote a reduced version of the FSM I posted above to try and debug the code. It tries to detect the sequence AB.

```
module moore_SM(clk, btn, rstN, state, rstLED);
//Port assignments
input clk;
input rstN;
input [2:0] btn;
output reg rstLED;
output reg [5:0] state;

//Internal Port Assignments
reg [1:0] w;
reg [2:0] y, Y;
reg [2:0] pstBtn;

//Define some parameters
parameter [1:0] A = 2'b00, B = 2'b01, C = 2'b11, DC = 2'b10;
parameter [2:0] S1 = 3'b000, S2 = 3'b001, S3 = 3'b010, S4 = 3'b011, S5 = 3'b100, S6 = 3'b101;

//Initialize some values to prevent Quartus from doing
initial 
    begin
        y = S1;
        Y = y;
        state = 0;
        rstLED = 0;
    end

always @(*)
    begin

        if(btn == pstBtn) begin w = DC; end

        else begin
            case(btn)
                3'b110: w = A;
                3'b101: w = B;
                3'b011: w = C;
                default: w = DC;
            endcase
        end

    end

always @(*)
    begin
        case(y)
            S1: begin
                    state = 6'b000001;
                    if(w == A) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end

            S2: begin
                    state = 6'b000010;
                    if(w == B) begin Y = S3; end
                    if(w == DC) begin Y = S2; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end

            S3: begin
                    state = 6'b000100;
                    if(w == DC) begin Y = S3; end
                    else begin Y = S1; end
                 end
            default: begin state = 6'b100000; Y = S1; end
        endcase
    end



//Update state and check for reset signal
always @(posedge clk, negedge rstN)
    begin
        pstBtn <= btn;

        if(rstN == 0) begin y <= S1; rstLED <= 1; end
        else begin y <= Y; rstLED <= 0; end
    end

endmodule
```

Note that I'm trying to "sample" the button state in the last always block. I've used this method in the past, but it does not seem to work here. Whenever I press a button, there is no change in state. I'm wondering if this is a timing issue now.

Comment: State should change on a clock edge, not combinatorialy

Comment: After I looked over my code again, I believe this is what it is doing. The combinational block defines the next state, `Y`, and then on a clock edge it updates the present state `y`.

Comment: No, the book is showing that 'Y' (which we would usually call *nextState* or *next_state* for clarity) is changing combinatorially. However that *nextState* value only gets registered on the following clock-edge: `always @(posedge clk) ... y <= Y;`

Comment: I realized that and changed my comment. However, I do believe this is what my code is doing. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Why do you use `always @(*)` and then `always @(w,y)` the synthesiser will always give you the behaviour of `always @(*)`. Using  `@(*)` is better practise. I find differentiating variable by case to be really bad practise, some tools are not case sensitive.

Comment: @Mlagma, I think your correct about your state. `Y` is your nextstate, `y` is your state. and `state` is a combinatorial output based on your y state

Comment: @Morgan The only reason I'm using always @(w,y) is because this is how my book defines combinational blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the button input is coming a switch rather than test stimulus it will be asynchronous  and so should be put through 2 meta-stability flip-flops. To change one state per button press create an edge detection.

Edge detection will create a 1 clock period wide pulse, resulting in 1 transition per press.

```
reg [2:0] btn0_meta;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rstN) begin
  if (~rstN) begin
    btn0_meta <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    btn0_meta <= {btn0_meta[1:0], btn[0]};
  end
end

reg btn0_posedge;
always @* begin
  btn0_posedge = btn0_meta[1] & ~btn_meta[2]; 
end
```

Do this for all button inputs and use the btnX_posedge in your state machine.

Comment: Thanks, I used the general behind this and it worked quite well.

Comment: @Mlagma glad we could help. For noisy buttons you might want to look up debouncing as well. Basically checking that the changed state of the button has lasted a certain amount of time, which reduced the chance of mechanical bouncing of switch contacts being detected as several button presses. Quite a few FPGAs take care of this for you though.

Comment: Yes, I know that the board I have uses a hardware debouncer, so this isn't too much of a concern for me. However, being that debouncing uses concepts similar to what I'm learning to deal with here, I've been reading a few articles on the subject. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Morgan- The edge detection logic assumes that btn[0] = 1 when the button is pressed and 0 otherwise? Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @JayK I have assumed button pressed is 1. If it is the other way around switch wich signal is inverted in the comparison. `btn0_negedge = ~btn0_meta[1] & btn_meta[2]; `