# How to generate a rising edge to control a shift register in verilog without a clock?

Tags: verilog, shift-register

First, let me explain what I am trying to do. I'm using a DE0 that has four seven-segment displays. My goal is to generate a string of text that scrolls across the displays, and the text string is based on user input. The user has three buttons that correspond to A, B, and C.

I've been able to create a "loop" that displays the text on the seven-segment displays, but I'm having difficulties grabbing the user input. My idea is to use a 9-bit shift register that takes user input and shifts past input down the chain so to speak.

Please not that I am quite new to verilog, and I'm still trying to figure out how to best think about it when writing the code. So far, I've found it best to visualize it in terms of physical hardware.

That said, this is what I'm visualizing:

New Input => Flip-Flop1 => FF2 => FF3 => FF4 => FF5 => FF6 => FF7 => FF8 => Discard Old Input

Using this idea, I wrote the following code:

```
wire[1:0] oneFF, twoFF, threeFF, fourFF, fiveFF, sixFF, sevenFF, eightFF;
reg[1:0] change;
wire bA, bB, bC; //Detects change in user input - either 1 or 0
parameter A = 2'b00; parameter B = 2'b01; parameter C = 2'b10;


//They are declared as wires since they really only interconnect portions of
  the hardware

FF One(clk, change, oneFF);
FF Two(clk, oneFF, twoFF);
FF Three(clk, twoFF, threeFF);
FF Four(clk, threeFF, fourFF);
FF Five(clk, fourFF, fiveFF);
FF Six(clk, fiveFF, sixFF);
FF Seven(clk, sixFF, sevenFF);
FF Eight(clk, sevenFF, eightFF);

module FF(clk, in, out);
  input clk;
  input [1:0] in;
  output reg [1:0] out;
  reg [31:0] count;

  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        count <= count + 1;
        if(count == 50000000) begin
        out <= in;
        count <= 0;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Then I wrote a module to detect input for the `change` register:

```
always @(*)
    begin

        if(bA) begin
            change = A;

        end

        if(bB) begin
            change = B;

        end

        if(bC) begin
            change = C;

        end
    end
```

This is where I encounter the problem. I can press a button, but the change in the first register will propagate through the chain. Obviously, this happens because all eight registers are tied to the same clock. This clock is running at 50mHz, so it appears to happen instantly. This is why I through in a counter in `module FF` so I can confirm my suspicion.

In order to address this, I attempted to throw in a single bit "update" in the `always` block to try and create a positive edge at each input, but this didn't work.

For instance:

```
  reg update;
  always @(*)
    begin
        update = 0;
        if(bA) begin
            change = A;
            update = ~update;
        end

        if(bB) begin
            update = ~update;
            change = B; 
        end

        if(bC) begin
            change = C;
            update = ~update;
        end
            update = 0;
    end
```

I would also change the module instantiations accordingly. This is also true if I change this block to non-blocking assignments.

I suspect there is a really simple solution for this problem. Basically, all I want is to have this effect

String Initialize: _ _ _ _ _ ...

Input:  A _ _ _ _ ...

Next Input: B A _ _ _ ...

instead of

Input: A A A A A ...

Next Input: B B B B B ...

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't attempt to generate edges or pulses from combinational logic. You can do what you want using just the clock, so you should stick with purely clocked logic.

If you want to generate an update strobe signal based on when user input changes, then store the previous value of the button, and generate an update anytime the button changes.

```
wire bA;
reg  bA_q;
reg  update;

always @(posedge clk) begin
   bA_q <= bA;
end

always @* begin
   if(bA && !bA_q) begin
        change = A;
        update = 1'b1;
   end else begin
        update = 1'b0;
        change = 0; //this can be anything, just set it so you don't infer a latch
   end
end
```

This generates the update strobe on any clock cycle that bA transitions from 0 to 1.

However, depending on your FPGA, you may need to **debounce** the button (some fpga do it automatically).

If your button is not debounced, it may rapidly flicker up and down when you press it, such that it appears to this circuit that you have repeatedly pressed the button several times. Therefore you may get several updates for a single press. This is a very common topic and I'm sure you can find additional resources about how to debounce a button if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Out of curiosity, I tried to apply this method to a FSM (which was another question of mine that I posted a few days ago). However, sampling the button did not work in that situation. Rather, I had to use multiple flip-flops in series to detect a change, which triggered a signal lasting the duration of a clock cycle.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between triggering a state change as in an FSM, and its application here?

Comment: @Mlagma `(bA && !bA_q)` is the same as the posedge detection in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22707129/97073), just another way of writing it. `bA_q` is another flip-flop, my answer added extra meta-stability flops because of the asynchronous button event. This answer is in-line [with previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22723754/97073), not conflicting.