# Verilog Muliple if else not working as expected

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am using three buttons on the Altera DE0 Board.

I declare it as

```
    input [2:0] Button;
    reg [2:0] y;
    parameter [2:0] S0 = 3'b000, S1 = 3'b001, S2 = 3'b010, S3 = 3'b011, S4 = 3'b100, S5 = 3'b101;
```

I have a nested if-else statement based on the values of the three buttons

```
always@(negedge (&Button))
//if(&Button == 0)
begin
if(Button == 3'b011)   // Button 2 is pressed
begin
if(y == S0)
    begin
    y = S1;
    end
end
else if(Button == 3'b101)  // Button 1 is pressed
begin
if (y == S1)
    begin
    y = S2;
    end
else if (y == S2)
    begin
    y = S3;
    end
end
else if(Button == 3'b110)  //This is the check on button 0, but this conditional statement does not work. 
begin
if(y == S2)
    begin
    y = S3;
    end
end
end

assign z =  (y == S0);     // z,z1,z2,z3 are LED's on the board
assign z1 = (y == S1);
assign z2 = (y == S2);
assign z3 = (y == S3);
```

When I use the first two buttons of the if-else statement  (button == 3'b011 and  button == 3'b101) labeled BUTTON2 and BUTTON1 on the DE0 board, the code works and y changes to the proper value as expected.

But when I try the third button in the if-else,  Button == 3'b011, labeled BUTTON0 on the DE0, nothing happens, y does not get the expected value.  I used 2 different DE0 boards and the same issue arises.

I think it has something to do with the

```
always@(negedge (&button))
```

in that the third button press is just not being detected.  But when I use code like

```
always@(negedge button[0] or negedge button[1] or negedge button[2])
```

other issues arise that I haven't been able to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about what hardware you are trying to model. `always @(negedge` or more generally edge triggered always blocks, are used to imply flip-flops which are generally driven by a clock and reset.

Data signals can be used as clocks as you would in a [Frequency Divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider#Digital_dividers). However your use of a unary `&` a combinatorial reduction operator will result in a glitchy clock in real hardware.

I mentioned thinking about what hardware you are implying because you have this construct:

```
always@(negedge button[0] or negedge button[1] or negedge button[2])
```

Which has no equivalent in hardware.

You may find this [Altera FSM example](http://www.altera.com/support/examples/verilog/ver_statem.html) helpful. You likely what to [implement edge detection from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22723754/97073) so you only change state once per button press.